# Do I have to loop over a mysqli-resultset if I know it's only one row?

Tags: php

I have a mysqli-resultset, which will only contain 1 row. I get the value like this at the moment:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query)->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
$result = $result[0];
```

Isn't there a more straight-forward way to do this?

Comment: This is actually *too simple* already. You do need to handle the case of a failed query gracefully. `mysqli_query` may return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 5.4:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query)->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)[0];
```

but it's missing error handling.

Comment: I don't know. I don't use `mysqli_query()` directly, I use a db wrapper that allows for `$db->query($query)->getOne();` If you're looking for concise but properly handled database routines, then I'd recommend you do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using fetch_array, why not just use fetch_row if you only ever want a single row?

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query)->fetch_row()
```